# SQL query does not work in Excel but works in Access

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

For the code listed below, it runs fine except for the first SQL query. I'm pulling address and state information from the workbook, and running a query on the information to find the count of how many times the address appears in the table. If I run the code and stop it before the query is sent to Access, I can pull the query command from the Immediate window, go to Access, and run the query no problem. However, if I just run the VBA program and have it send the query to Access, I keep getting 0 for the result. So long story short, the query will run in Access and provide the correct result, but when Excel VBA sends the query to Access, I keep getting zero for the result (and no error messages). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Dim DatabaseFileName As String, connectionstring As String   

connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & DatabaseFileName & "; Persist Security Info=False;"

Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open connectionstring

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset, SQL As String
Dim ExecSQL As New ADODB.Command

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    For I = 2 To 1235
        SQL = ""
        If .Cells(I, 7) <> "" Then
            SQL = "SELECT Count(VRSC_CUSTOMER_SITES.SITE_ID)  AS GCOUNT into [GVRCount1] "
            SQL = SQL & "FROM (VRSC_CUSTOMER_SITES) "
            SQL = SQL & "WHERE ((VRSC_CUSTOMER_SITES.SITE_STREET Like " & Chr(34) & .Cells(I, 7) & Chr(34) & ") AND ((VRSC_CUSTOMER_SITES.SITE_ST)="
            SQL = SQL & Chr(34) & .Cells(I, 5) & Chr(34) & ") AND ((VRSC_CUSTOMER_SITES.SITE_PHONE) Not Like ""999*""));"
            
            rs.Open SQL, conn
            
            SQL = "SELECT * FROM [GVRCount1]"
            rs.Open SQL
            
            .Cells(I, 8).CopyFromRecordset rs
            
        End If
    Next
End With
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)

    .Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
    
End With

conn.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you open rs the first time? You don't use it and throw it at once away when opening the second query. Makes no sense to me.

Comment: Yes you are correct. So please disregard that part. I have since deleted the "SQL = "SELECT * FROM [GVRCount1]"" and the "rs.Open SQL" part. So I'm basically just looking at the SQL stuff. I'm still getting the same issue.

Comment: I have had to troubleshoot SQL via ADODB like this before and I would recommend starting with a "no fail" SQL statement like `SELECT * FROM [VRSC_CUSTOMER_SITES$]` first to see if it's the SQL or your connection.  If that works, I would comment out and test your more complex SQL statement line by line un-commenting it (with modifications to make it still work).   I don't query against MS-Access ever, but when I write my SQL queries to go against an Excel workbook (used as a database), I have my tables in SQL written as: `[Table$]` with the "$" at the end. Double-check?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Essentially, the issue is due to the `LIKE` operator. Whenever you run an Access query over an ODBC/OLEDB connection, the wildcard to use is the current ANSI version `%`. However, in Access GUI, the wildcard uses the older version, `*`. See [MSDN docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-wildcards-in-queries-and-parameters-in-access-ec057a45-78b1-4d16-8c20-242cde582e0b) discussing this wildcard usage.

To be compatible between Excel and Access (VBA or GUI), consider undocumented `ALIKE` operator to only use `%`. Additionally, use ADO parameterization using ADO command and avoid concatenation of values to SQL statement. Below replaces the first `LIKE` with `=` since no wildcard is used and the make-table action using `INTO` was removed. Also, `New` is removed from any `Dim` lines.

```vb
Dim DatabaseFileName As String, connectionstring As String, SQL As String
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, ExecSQL As ADODB.Command
Dim I As Long

connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" _
                    & DatabaseFileName & "; Persist Security Info=False;"

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open connectionstring

' PREPARED STATEMENT WITH ? PLACEHOLDERS
SQL = "SELECT COUNT(v.SITE_ID) AS GCOUNT " _
    & "FROM VRSC_CUSTOMER_SITES v " _
    & "WHERE v.SITE_STREET = ? " _
    & "  AND v.SITE_ST = ? " _
    & "  AND v.SITE_PHONE NOT ALIKE '999%';" _

For I = 2 To 1235
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(I, 7) <> "" Then
        Set ExecSQL = New ADODB.Command
        With ExecSQL
            .ActiveConnection = conn
            .CommandText = SQL
            .CommandType = adCmdText

            '  BIND PARAMETERS
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("street_param", adVarchar, adParamInput, 255, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(I, 7))
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("st_param", adVarchar, adParamInput, 255, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(I, 5))

            '  EXECUTE QUERY AND BIND INTO RECORDSET
            Set rs = .Execute
        End With
            
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(I, 8).CopyFromRecordset rs
    End If
Next I

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
    .Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
End With
```

Comment: Thank you @Parfait and wackojacko1997. Parfait you were indeed correct about the percent operator. All of my data used "*" as the wildcard character. When I changed the "*" to a "%", my query worked. My simpler queries worked (per wacko's recommendation), so Parfait your suggestion made sense. Thanks guys for all of the help!